# Pipes in Angular2

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I'm trying to create my first custom pipe in angular 2 but it seems that I'm missing something in the code prevent me from getting the desired output: I want to display only the names where Type is equal to 'T' or 'A':

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name:"search"})
export class search{
  transform (value){
   x = [];
   x = items.filter(item => item.Type = 'T');
   x = items.filter(item => item.Type = 'A');
   return x;
  }
}

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
Pipes: [search],
template: `
  <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <br>
  <li *ngFor = "#c of todos.Name">{{c | search}}</li>
`
})
export class AppComponent { 

 todos = [
   {"Name":"Sleep","Type":"T"},
   {"Name":"Eat","Type":"E"},
   {"Name":"Work","Type":"T"},
   {"Name":"Jump","Type":"A"}
 ];

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

FIrst thing you have to change your HTML template to below like `pipe` should get applied on `todos` on `ngFor`

```
template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <li *ngFor = "let c of todos | search">
    {{c.Name}}
  </li>`
```

And then change your `Pipe` to below like `@eltonkamami` already suggested

```
@Pipe({name:"search"})
export class search implements PipeTransform{
   transform (items){
      return items.filter(item => item.Type == 'T' || item.Type == 'A');
   }
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/barByYn7nlZOeeUardo6?p=preview)

Comment: still I'm not getting any output, can you please tell me whats the proper way to import the pipe if it was in independent file ?

Comment: Have you checked mine plunkr? Are you using NgModule?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to combine your `Array#filter` functionality like so

```
@Pipe({name:"search"})
export class search implements PipeTransform{
  transform (value){
    return items.filter(item => item.Type == 'T' || item.Type == 'A');
  }
}
```

As long as `items` is an array the `Array#filter` will always return an array, so no need to set x to an empty array.

The way you are doing it now.
  1. You set x to an empty array
  2. x is all the items with a type of `T`
  3. x is all the items with a type of `A`

so x will always have the items with a type of `A` (or be empty if there are none)

Comment: the names are not displayed in the html page :(